# Django dictionary with the same value

Tags: python, django, dictionary, django-views

I'm trying to create a dictionary with some specific values but it gets the same values multiple times:

```
readers = Readers.objects.all()
count = 0
readersResult = {}
test = {
    "avatar": "",
    "firstName": "",
    "percent": "",
    "lastName": ""
}
for reader in readers:
    test["percent"] = "value from another place"
    test["firstName"] = reader.firstName
    test["lastName"] = reader.lastName
    test["avatar"] = reader.avatar

    print("TEST: ", test)

    readersResult[count] = test
    count = count + 1

print("RESULT":, readersResult)
```

My output is:

```
web_1  | TEST:  {'avatar': '/images/avatars/71.png', 'firstName': 'abc', 'percent': '37.08999158957107', 'lastName': 'def'}
web_1  | TEST:  {'avatar': '/images/avatars/61.png', 'firstName': 'abc', 'percent': '4.037005887300253', 'lastName': 'def'}
web_1  | RESULT:  {0: {'avatar': '/images/avatars/61.png', 'firstName': 'abc', 'percent': '4.037005887300253', 'lastName': 'def'}, 1: {'avatar': '/images/avatars/61.png', 'firstName': 'abc', 'percent': '4.037005887300253', 'lastName': 'def'}}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `test` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, in your code, you make a `dict` named test, and then in each loop iteration you add it again to the `readersResult`.

```
test = {
    "avatar": "",
    "firstName": "",
    "percent": "",
    "lastName": ""
}
for reader in readers:
    test["percent"] = "value from another place"
    test["firstName"] = reader.firstName
    test["lastName"] = reader.lastName
    test["avatar"] = reader.avatar

    print("TEST: ", test)

    readersResult[count] = test
    count = count + 1
```

You need to create a new `dict` with each loop iteration. So exchange this part of your code to this:

```
for reader in readers:
    test = {}
    test["percent"] = "value from another place"
    test["firstName"] = reader.firstName
    test["lastName"] = reader.lastName
    test["avatar"] = reader.avatar

    print("TEST: ", test)

    readersResult[count] = test
    count = count + 1
```

PS: You don't need to use the below code to define the keys in the dictionary and then set its values somewhere else. So you can change:

```
teste = {
    "avatar": [],
    "firstName": [],
    "percent": [],
    "lastName": []
}
```

with:

```
test = {}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning the same dictionary (`test`) to multiple entries in `readersResult`, as opposed to making a new one for each `reader`.

Comment: How it should be ?

Answer (score -3):

You can use a list as the dictionary value:

```
readers = Readers.objects.all()
count = 0
readersResult = {}
test = {
    "avatar": [],
    "firstName": [],
    "percent": [],
    "lastName": []
}
for reader in readers:
    test["percent"].append("value from another place")
    test["firstName"].append(reader.firstName)
    test["lastName"].append(reader.lastName)
    test["avatar"].append(reader.avatar)

    print("TEST: ", test)

    readersResult[count] = test
    count = count + 1

print("RESULT: ", readersResult)
```

Examples can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-ways-to-create-a-dictionary-of-lists/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).